# How to set enum field as Integer via Hibernate to db?

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, enums

I have integer column as "status" in my db.

My enum class:

```
public enum MemberStatus {
   PASSIVE(0),ACTIVE(1);

   private int value;

   private MemberStatus(int value) {
      this.value = value;
   }

   public int getValue() {
      return value;
   }
```

}

My entity field:

```
@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
private MemberStatus status;
```

Hibernate Log:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "status" is of type **integer** but expression is of type **bytea**.
>   Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the **expression.bytea**

I use PostgreSQL. How to solve this problem? Any idea?

Comment: Are you using org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect?

Comment: I use it : hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect

Comment: If you have control over the database (a client won't need to deploy on MySQL), then you can use string representation for the enum and use a Postgres enum type for the column, and everything will Just Work, with the advantages of a DB-native enum.

Comment: @Gyhot have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use a converter.

It's the cleanest solution i came to because:

- you no longer have an issue with the order in which you add values to
  the enum or if you refactor the enum elements name
- you have more flexibility on what database type your column has

You can define the field as:

```
@Column(name = "status", nullable = false)
@Convert(converter = MemberStatusEnumConverter.class)
private MemberStatus status;
```

The enum becomes simpler:

```
public enum MemberStatus {
   PASSIVE,
   ACTIVE;
}
```

And your converter class  MemberStatusEnumConverter:

```
import javax.persistence.AttributeConverter;
import javax.persistence.Converter;

@Converter
public class MemberStatusEnumConverter implements    
AttributeConverter<MemberStatus,Integer>{
    @Override
    public Integer convertToDatabaseColumn(MemberStatus attribute) {
        switch (attribute) {
            case PASSIVE:
                return new Integer(0);
            case COUNTYLEVEL:
                return new Integer(1);
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown" + attribute);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MemberStatus convertToEntityAttribute(Integer dbData) {
        if (dbData == 0){
            return MemberStatus.PASSIVE;
        } else if (dbData == 1){
            return MemberStatus.ACTIVE;
        }
        else{
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown" + dbData);
        }
    }
}
```

[This article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/mapping-enums-done-right) describes the solution i implemented for your example.